# Not enough permanent generation memory. How increase memory?

Tags: java, youtrack

I installed youtrack. Begin to adjust. And my message is shown:

> "Not enough permanent generation memory. Please, refer to
>   documentation on how to increase it."

I went to the documentation. Sought there, tried to register at startup

```
exec $JAVA_HOME -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -jar $JAR"youtrack.jar" $PORT >> $LOG 2>&1 &
```

tried to set parameter.

```
java -XX:PermSize=1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -jar /usr/local/youtrack/youtrack.jar 8112
```

Still does not work. I use Ubuntu Server 10.04

Comment: Included logic and at random. Crossed two options did so, it's work:
`code`exec $JAVA_HOME -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -jar $JAR"youtrack.jar" $PORT >> $LOG 2>&1 &`code`

Answer (score 4):

This has worked for me:

`java -XX:MaxPermSize=150m -Xmx512m -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar youtrack-<version>.jar 8080`

Answer (score 2):

JVM flag that controls PermGen size is `-XX:MaxPermSize`. Try to modify startup script for youtrack like this:

```
java -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Xmx1024m -jar /usr/local/youtrack/youtrack.jar 8112
```

Although, be advised that this may not work on Windows because Tomcat loves ignoring startup scripts. You may need to specify these JVM flags in Windows service properties window.

Or maybe a little bit fewer than 1024m, not sure you really need that much.